# Binding Windows Forms to SqlConnectionStringBuilder

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Could someone show tell me why when I try to bind a text box to a  SqlConnectionStringBuilder instance it doesn't work and I receive the error.

"Cannot bind to the property or column DataSource on the DataSource.\r\nParameter name: dataMember"

It seems like binding manager can't find the property when it reflects to find it.

If I write a 'do nothing' wrapper that just forwards get/set operations it works as expected.

I've reflected SqlConnectionStringBuilder object and didn't see anything that would lead me to think that I couldn't bind to it directly to it's properties.

Here's a mock up of the code I'm using...

```
public partial class frmMain : Form {

    private BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();

    public frmMain() {
        InitializeComponent();

        //bindingSource.DataSource = typeof(SqlConnectionStringBuilderWrapper);
        bindingSource.DataSource = typeof(SqlConnectionStringBuilder);

        tbDataSource.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource, "DataSource");

        initializeConnectionStrings();
    }

    private void initializeConnectionStrings() {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder defaultBuilder = null;
        cmbConnectionStrings.DataSource = SqlConnectionStrings.ConnectionBuilders(out defaultBuilder);

        //bindingSource.DataSource = new SqlConnectionStringBuilderWrapper(defaultBuilder);
        bindingSource.DataSource = defaultBuilder;

        cmbConnectionStrings.SelectedItem = defaultBuilder;
    }
}

public class SqlConnectionStringBuilderWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged {private SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = null;

    public SqlConnectionStringBuilderWrapper(SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder) { this.builder = builder; }
    public SqlConnectionStringBuilder Builder { get { return builder; } set {} }

    public string DataSource {
        get { return builder.DataSource; }
        set {
            if (builder.DataSource != value) {
                builder.DataSource = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DataSource");
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

If I change the DataSource assignments to the commented versions.  It works.  I just don't understand why the wrapper is needed.

Thanks!

Comment: what's in that wrapper?

Comment: I suggest the you review the Remarks section of  [BindingSource.DataSource Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) for permissible types.

Comment: I have reviewed the section you mention.  I didn't see where the composition of the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class disqualifys it as a valid data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time reader, first time posting.  Here goes...

**Setting the stage:**

• SqlConnectionStringBuilder inherits from DbConnectionStringBuilder

• DbConnectionStringBuilder implements the interfaces: IDictionary, ICollection, IEnumerable, and ICustomTypeDescription

The usage of these interfaces on the class is "odd"... meaning there is no collection of connection strings (there is only one).  The usage of these interfaces is to manage the key/value pairs of the string elements WITHIN the "DataSource/ConnectionString" property.

The reason your sample works when you created a wrapper that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged is because a BindingSource knows how to pull from the INotifyPropertyChanged interface without getting confused about the derived classes implementation of IDictionary/ICollection/IEnumerable/ICustomTypeDescription (IE you bound to a concrete class that only implements one interface INotifyPropertyChanged).  Besides your workaround I think an alternative would be to use the SqlConnection class instead (it has no collection interfaces associated).

The best deep dive post about the internals of the binding source class was this blog: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial.  Check out the section "How does it work?"  I stopped pursuing the inner workings of binding source after reading this and will do some magic arm waving to say that issue #1 is somewhere inside that mess :P

**Issue #1**
I could not implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and ANY of the IDictionary/ICollection/IEnumerable/ICustomTypeDescription, and use a "bindingSource" to bind a non collection type property (string specifically) on the class.  In your case this is the "DataSource" property which is a string not a “collection” type.

I created a sample class that implements both INotifyPropertyChanged and ANY of the other interfaces (IDictionary/ICollection/IEnumerable/ICustomTypeDescription).  Binding never worked to the single property using a Textblock.Text binding.  I can't find any results at all for people trying to do this and why it would fail... apparently no one tries to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in conjunction with any of the other supported bindable interfaces... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/interfaces-related-to-data-binding.  Documentation is sparse when trying to use a bindingSource on a class that implements multiple of the available/valid interface types.

**Issue #2**
BindingSource objects cannot see inherited properties from parent classes on the derived class.  While not the root cause of your issue, SqlConnectionStringBuilder being derived complicates the situation.

The best explanation: [Why BindingSource component cannot see inherited properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165824/why-bindingsource-component-cannot-see-inherited-properties)
It looks like Microsoft acknowledged the issue and closed the feature request: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/431273/interface-inheritance-bug
Additional info: [Winforms databinding with interface inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344760/winforms-databinding-with-interface-inheritance)
Best logical reason provided in the last link above – “Interfaces support Multiple Inheritance but classes do not.”

While this is not directly related to your issue, I'm assuming that issue #1 is a similar flaw to issue #2 with the internals of the "BindingSource" class not being able to specify which interface to bind to given the existing syntax parameters.